How can I fix this userscript to work in a browser that has committed the inputs it uses to be its own shortcuts?
The idea of this userscript is that when browsing search results, you can hold different combinations of three keys to indicate whether that tag will be added to your search query with an AND, NOT or OR search operator.
The intended outcome is that holding Alt adds the next tag alongside with no symbol, Alt+Shift gives you the NOT operator and Alt+Shift+Control gives you the OR before the search is resubmitted.
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll("td div.tags");
wrappers.forEach(function(div) {
    div.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        if (ev.altKey === true && ev.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
            ev.preventDefault();

            var anchor = ev.target,
                linkQuery = new URLSearchParams(anchor.search);
            var tag = linkQuery.get('taglist'),
                taglist;
            if (tag) {
                if (ev.shiftKey === true) tag = '-' + tag;
                else if (ev.ctrlKey === true) tag = '|' + tag;
                var pageQuery = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                taglist = pageQuery.get('taglist').split(' ');
                if (taglist.indexOf(tag) === -1) taglist.push(tag);
                pageQuery.set('taglist', taglist.join(' '));

                window.location.search = pageQuery.toString();
            }
        }
    }, true);
});

I'd been using this made by a former colleague in Chrome on MacOS and I'd already had to make a gentle tweak for it to use sommand instead of shift as control+clicking brought up a context menu. The code itself works and has served me well.
I am now using Firefox and this problem has amplified. Control+click continutes to open a context menu. Shift+click opens the link in a new window without the effect of the script taking place, command+click does the same but opens a new tab in the background. Option still works as an equivalent for alt and I can successfully activate the first of the three combinations but this is where I got stuck.
Here is what I attempted between then and now.

I tried to reconfigure Firefox but there seems to be no flexibility on any of the standard keyboard shortcuts.

The extent of my JavaScript is in my own userscripts pushing DOM elements around. I spent a few hours reading documentation and trying to fuse the example code into this script but I just couldn't get anything going. I have very limited understanding of the syntax and find how things chain together and pass data between them unintuitive. But I unsuccessfully tried to apply my rudimentary programming ability in other languages to this situation using the documentation.

I tried to replace the buttons being held down with other less contested buttons being held down but it seems like JS's EventHandler sees those four as special. I tried to use 'repeat' but had no success, and tried to use other modifier style keys that were more easily recognised in an on/off state but they were either out of specification for Mac Firefox or I just couldn't get any response from them. This seems like the most obvious and ideal solution.

I tried to set variables with buttons and substitute the if (ev.shiftKey === true) bits with my own variables but I didn't get anything to fire successfully.

I swapped out 'mouseover' for 'click' as the event and it did work but this was not a practical solution and felt more like a sign to throw in the towel and ask for help.



*Suppress Default Browser Behaviors:
The primary issue is that key combinations like Ctrl+Click and Shift+Click trigger browser behaviors (e.g., opening context menus or links in new windows/tabs). To prevent these default actions, you can use ev.preventDefault() and ev.stopPropagation() in the event handler.
*Use Different Keys or Customizable Shortcuts:
Since the standard modifiers conflict with browser shortcuts, consider using less common keys or allowing the user to customize the key bindings. You can modify the script to detect alternative keys that aren't tied to browser behaviors.
Example Implementation:
Here's an updated version of your script with these considerations:
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll("td div.tags");

wrappers.forEach(function(div) {
    div.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        // Prevent default behavior and stop propagation
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();

        if (ev.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
            var anchor = ev.target,
                linkQuery = new URLSearchParams(anchor.search);
            var tag = linkQuery.get('taglist'),
                taglist;

            if (tag) {
                // Use different key combinations to avoid conflict
                if (ev.altKey && ev.shiftKey && !ev.ctrlKey) {
                    tag = '-' + tag; // NOT operator
                } else if (ev.altKey && ev.ctrlKey) {
                    tag = '|' + tag; // OR operator
                }

                var pageQuery = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                taglist = pageQuery.get('taglist') ? pageQuery.get('taglist').split(' ') : [];

                if (taglist.indexOf(tag) === -1) {
                    taglist.push(tag);
                }

                pageQuery.set('taglist', taglist.join(' '));
                window.location.search = pageQuery.toString();
            }
        }
    }, true);
});

ev.preventDefault() and ev.stopPropagation(): These prevent the default actions like opening context menus or new tabs.
Alternative Key Combinations: I adjusted the key combinations to prevent conflicts. Alt+Shift and Alt+Ctrl are used to add NOT and OR operators, respectively.
